# Postgres query with limit that selects all records with similar identifier

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks something like this:

| customer_id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 1 | 456 |
| 2 | 789 |
| 2 | 101 |
| 2 | 121 |
| 2 | 123 |
| 3 | 123 |
| 4 | 456 |

What I would like to do is perform a `SELECT` combined with a `LIMIT X` to get X number of records as well as any other records that have the same `customer_id`

Example query: `SELECT customer_id, data FROM table ORDER BY customer_id LIMIT 3;`
This query returns:

| customer_id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 1 | 456 |
| 2 | 789 |

I'd like a query that will look at the last `customer_id` value and return all remaining records that match beyond the `LIMIT` specified. Is it possible to do this in a single operation?

Desired output:

| customer_id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 1 | 456 |
| 2 | 789 |
| 2 | 101 |
| 2 | 121 |
| 2 | 123 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Postgres 13 can use `with ties`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by customer_id
fetch first 3 rows with ties;
```

In earlier versions you can use `in`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.customer_id in (select t2.customer_id
                        from t t2
                        order by t2.customer_id
                        limit 3
                       );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use corelated subquery with `count` as follows:

```
Select t.*
  From t
 Where 3 >= (select count(distinct customer_id)
               From t tt 
              where t.customer_id >= tt.customer_id)
```